# I cannot clear input on submitting form

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, redux-form

I am using reactJs coupled with redux-form.

And also using the **semantic ui react library**

When i want to submit my form, i don't want my page to be refreshed. Instead i want to reset my form after the submission.

Unfortunately, i can't clear my input whereas i set the state to void the value.

```js
/** Form component **/

<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmitAction)}>
        <Field name="input" component={renderTitleInput} onChangeAction={this.handleInputChange} defaultValue={this.state.input} />
          <input type="submit"  name="submit" />
      </Form>
      
      
      
/** HandleSubmit function **/

handleSubmitAction = (e) => {
  this.setState({input:''})
}
```

The field remain filled after submitting the form.

Any suggestion ? thanks

Comment: I don't know how semantic ui works, but you're changing the `defaultValue` of the field. Try setting the `input` value to `this.state.input`, and not the `defaultValue`, or the `value` of the `Field` component if there is one.

Comment: Thanks. It's solved. You're right `value` is more appropriate than `defaultValue` but `Field` component doesn't either recognize `value` attribute so to get this work i need to pass it via a custom `fieldValue` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What you created is an uncontrolled component, which means that update must be handled through the DOM. To do that you need to add the `ref`attribute to get access to the DOM element in the form submit callback. Here is the changes you need to make.

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmitAction)}>
    <Field name="input" component={renderTitleInput} onChangeAction={this.handleInputChange} defaultValue={this.state.input} ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
      <input type="submit"  name="submit" />
</Form>
/** HandleSubmit function **/

handleSubmitAction = (e) => {
  // This can be used when using controlled component. 
  //this.setState({input:''})
  this.input.val = '';
}
```

But maybe what you want is to handle it as [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Comment: Thank for helping. I solved this issue. details explained  above.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I want to clear input after submit button is clicked & use the functional component. here is an example of how I reset the value of input field after submitting.
Set value of the `input` to `state value` & when state value is reset input field get reset and the field is empty.

```
const [cancelInput, setCancelInput] = useState('');

const inputChange = (event, data) => {
  // console.log(data)
  setCancelInput(data.value)
}

const handleClick = (e) => {
  setCancelInput(e.target.value)
}

<Input onChange={inputChange} placeholder='Type cancel here' value={cancelInput}/>
<Button color='red' onClick={handleClick} disabled={cancelInput !== 'cancel'} loading={loading} >Cancel</Button>
```